# How to use MDC components within lit element?

Tags: mdc-components, lit-element, lit-html

I am trying to use a mdc-component (say mdc-textfield) within a lit element. Looks like I have to import both css and js files into the element.

I'm quite unsure of how to import css into the lit-element.

BTW I use `polymer serve` without any preprocessors or compiler.

Comment: You probably should try using the material web components https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components , though most are still in a pre-release status

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to wait for [Material Component Web Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components)

But answering your question, to use MCD you need to use sass, then you will need a pre-compiler. Once you have compiled to CSS you can import it into your component:

```
const anyStyle = html`<style src="path/to/compiled/style.css"></style>`;
```

I recommend to use a watcher to automatically build the sass files while you are running `polymer serve`